# Azure Application Gateway is striping request body when it comes from APIGEE

Tags: azure, azure-functions, apigee, azure-application-gateway

When APIGEE is trying to hit API which is deployed in Azure as function app which has app gateway integrated, but when the request is coming it is stripping the request body. as the result we are getting 400 bad request we are clueless what is happening here, any help would be welcomed

Comment: One thing to look out for is GET vs. POST. I noticed that Azure will not take GET requests with a body

Comment: it is POST only from APIGEE side

Comment: Use Apigee's ability to 'trace' the Apigee southbound call to your Azure-hosted target endpoint, to validate that the body is actually present in the call. Possibly it is being stripped out upstream: It may be that an Apigee policy is stripping it, not the Azure app gateway doing so.

Comment: They have actually traced that and showed us screen shots where all the bytes (content-length) is tranferred to the up stream (Azure app gateway)

Answer (score 0):

•   As per your explanation, you are sending a POST request to the application gateway in Azure behind which the function app is deployed. Thus, **when the request from Apigee hits the application gateway endpoint, the information in body of the request gets eaten or disappeared. This happens with specific API proxies only, in this case, the apigee request sent is considering the application gateway deployed as an unacceptable API proxy**. Thus, I would request you to please take the following steps: -

a)  Gather a TCP dump when the API request was made with **NGINX/Wireshark logs** and analyze it to confirm the **target port as 443**.

b)  Check any message being sent from the **message processor to the backend server** and check any message that states as below in the logs: -

```
  [Unencrypted HTTP protocol detected over encrypted port, could indicate a dangerous misconfiguration.]
```

c)  And if the **target server definition was created without ‘SSLInfo’ section**, then the above message is encountered in the logs. Then `update the target server definition with the correct ‘SSLInfo’ section to make it secure`.

d)  Then **restart both the ‘Message Processors’ on the apigee as well as the Azure side** to get the latest definition of the target server.

e)  Also, check if the `encoding specified in the HTTP request header ‘Content-Encoding’ is valid or not and the payload format sent by the client as a part of the HTTP request matches the encoding format specified in the ‘Content-Encoding’ header or not`.

•   The error that you are encountering is a result of the above stated scenario. As a result, you can fix the issue by `sending the request header as Content-Encoding:<payload format> and the request payload also in the same format`. An example of doing the same is given below: -

```
  curl -v "https://HOSTALIAS/v1/testgzip" -H "Content-Encoding: gzip" -X POST -d @request_payload.gz
```

For more details regarding the above, kindly refer to the documentation link below: -

https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/troubleshoot/runtime/400-decompressionfailureatrequest

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, I will do above tests and get back to you with result.

Comment: Hi @manasa, did the suggested solution work for you? Do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot or else do accept it for helping other community members.